# When the majority votes against someone

Tags: law, democracy

## Background

Mr. X has recently joined a group of friends. The group voted that Mr. X has to buy lunch for the group. The group had two arguments:

1. They argued that it's according to democracy and the vote of the majority.
2. They argued that the group had a law. The law is that every new member has to buy lunch in order to join the group.

## Question

Now, how can Mr. X argue with them? For each of the above arguments, there is a question:

1. Does democracy allow the majority to vote against the interest of a member?
2. Is the prerequisite law for *joining the group* compatible with democracy?

Comment: A group of friends voting on something like making a new friend pay for a meal really has nothing to do with politics or government as that sort of vote has none of the same meanings or results as a vote related to a government.

Comment: @sfxedit  I'm not sure I like the new title.  It doesn't match the question.  The question is about a group of friends, but the title makes it seem like it a about States. Perhaps this is what the OP intended, but it jarrs for me.#

Comment: @JoeW Technically any interaction with other people is political. Or at least any interaction that relates to  negotiations with other people, whether that's about the code of conduct, the decision making process, the subject of the decision making process and so on. And that relates to the big politics as well as the small politics, the difference is just that in terms of the big politics it's harder to quit. Like in that case Mr. X could just say "Y'know what, I'm out." While in terms of countries and governments that is a lot harder. Though as an analogy that still works.

Comment: @haxor789 A group of friends deciding on something isn't political in the scope of this site.

Comment: @JoeW Sure it's not world politics and it's actual content is likely nothing that could be answered by a stranger and their internal arguments would rather be a subject of rhetoric and psychology, but that's not really the point. In that case it's merely an analogy and which certainly imperfect it works here as an illustration of the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Would a throwaway line at the end about how democracies handle something like that fix the criticisms?

Comment: @bharring The question is about interactions with friends and would be a fit on interpersonal.stackexchange and not here. Just because you use the word vote doesn't mean it is political in nature

Comment: @bharring no, because it still is a personal interaction question and not a politics one. If the goal of the question is the majority vote forcing something on the minority vote there are many ways to write a question about that.

Comment: I read the personal interactions as a way to phrase a concern the writer has about democracy scaled up

Comment: @bharring In that case what isn't about politics as you can say most everything someone does is related to politics.

Comment: @JamesK No, the question is not about a "group of friends" but the *democratic process* where things are decided by *consensus*. And a common issue that crops up in democracy is majoritarianism and minority rights. So my title and edit do provide the necessary context and improve the question. (And it got some good answers too before my edits were reverted).

Comment: @sfxedit it's not your question.  The quesiton says "Mr. X has recently joined a group of friends. The group voted that Mr. X has to buy lunch for the group."   There is nothing in the OP's question that says it is about anything but a group of friends.  If the OP had wanted to ask about democratic processes in general, or in the case of a government or state they could have.

Comment: @JamesK Communicating through the written word is harder because it is easy to miss context or misinterpret - a good example is how you (and others) are focusing only on the "group of friends" while ignoring the actual questions which ask about the *democratic process* within them. Hence I added the necessary context so that the question is not closed (which tends to discourage user participation). If you still felt it was lacking, it would have helped if you had contributed to it. If the edits were unhelpful, the questioner is free to revert our edits and make their intent clear.

Comment: I didn't vote to close.  I just think a comment would have been better than editing to make what you think the question ought to have been.  Or if you are going to be bold, then explain in detail what you've done.

Answer (score 7):

Complicated, but mostly 'yes' to your enumerated questions and 'no' to the example to illustrate it.

- A democracy can vote against the interests of any one member. In a short-sighted interpretation, it is in my personal interest that I do *not* pay taxes while everybody *else* does, yet a democracy can vote that everybody pays. (It is in my enlightened self-interest to establish the principle that everybody *including myself* pays, so that others don't try to opt out as well, but I might not be looking at the long run.)
- A state can have requirements from their citizens which are not evenly spread. There is, for instance, the military draft. This tends to hit young men in preference to older ones, and males in preference to females. Assuming a somewhat stable policy, every male goes to the draft at some time, yet when it is introduced, it hits only present and coming generations.
- This 'group of friends' is not the same as a state. States are understood to be sovereign, groups of friends are not. Notably, on average people are *born* into states.
  There is the concept of an [inter-generational contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergenerationality#Contract), which is not a contract in the *legal* sense but in the [social](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract) sense. This is widely seen as legitimate, unlike a [pyramid scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_scheme) which is not, because the inter-generational contract assumes the same size of each generation. (Where that size assumption fails, as in most Western countries, there are problems.)

But as mentioned a group of friends is no state. So one question would be if they had communicated this 'entry fee' in advance. And another would be if Mr. X is free to say, "why, then I don't want your friendship." One is free to opt out of a circle of friends. One is not free to opt out of a state, at least not without leaving it.

Within the contract law framework of a state, one might also ask:
'Mr. X has joined a golf club, they *retroactively* raise application fees.' -- no.
'Mr. X has joined a golf club, failing to read that they have an application fee.' -- yes.
'Mr. X has joined a golf club, and they vote to increase the annual dues.' -- yes.
'Mr. X has joined a motorcycle gang where juniors are expected to give their criminal gains to seniors.' -- no, but going to civil trial over that may be unhealthy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm going to study it thoroughly.

Comment: @user3405291, you will find plenty of discussion about the 'Tyranny of the Majority.' A good democracy protects *reasonable* demands of the minority against *unreasonable* action of the majority, but it does not allow individuals or minorities to dictate just any decision which affects them. Compare the debate about gerrymandering in the US, and what is or is not fair in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

Om's answer is better, but felt more should be said. Read his first.

Most Western states are *constitutional* democracies instead of "pure" democracies for this very reason.

Using the US as an example. I would expect similar in Western countries (as its a core tenent of Western philosophy)

The US Founding Fathers were concerned with the Tyranny of the Majority, which is one of the handful of reasons democracy in the US is limited by its constitution. If you got 60% of the country to vote to make Bob pay for dinner, they would not be legally able to do so.

At the more broad level, the US Constitution protects the rights of individuals regardless of public opinion (mostly through the Bill of Rights). 60% of the country can't outlaw your faith, make you be quiet, or step on any of your other rights (even ones not listed!).

At a more specific level, the government signaling an individual out to pay for dinner would be a Bill of Atainder, which is explicitly banned in the Constitution. No rule can apply to a specific individual. And (under the 14th) all rules must apply to all individuals.

So we can't use the government to make Bob buy us dinner.

Comment: I'm not sophisticated regarding political knowledge. So, your post is more understandable to me. Thanks :)

Comment: A constitution isn't necessarily making it a less pure democracy. If you'd argue against the purity of the U.S. democracy you'd rather cite stuff like representation rather than direct democracy, Gerrymandering and other forms of disproportionate representation, like how technically a minority of less than 25% of the population can select the government, making it the tyranny of a minority. But unless you treat the constitution as above the law making processes (like a holy scripture or whatnot) you'd not be violating the idea of a democracy.

Comment: @haxor789 the Supremacy clause explicitly places the US Constitution above the law making process. It's what the answer is about.

Comment: @bharring No what I mean would be something like "cannot be amended" where it's literally outside of the process. Afaik the constitution can still be changed by the constituents if they wanted to, right?

Comment: Changing the Constitution requires such steps where you'd need over 66% support *in both houses* for a change to start, then 75% of States. The Constitution can't be changed by Congress regardless of majority.

Comment: @haxor780 The U.S. Constitution has been changed via an amendment process no less than 27 times in the nation's history, but these changes are quite rare compared to the number of ordinary laws and amendments to those laws.   The sheer number of votes needed to do so makes it very difficult to do but not impossible, and certainly unlikely on hot button issues that have a near even split of pro and con supporters.

Comment: Less than 27, as the first 10 amendments were a package deal.

Answer (score 2):

The primary way of dealing with majoritarianism is by encouraging the majority of people to think of society as a system and developing their political intelligence and awareness of history.

This is not something automatically guaranteed by any particular electoral system, and is in stark contrast to encouraging people to think of an election like a marketplace, and as a context for pursuing their own pure self-interest.

Traditionally, churches and organised religion covered much of this kind of political education function, and were responsible for keeping and reproducing the knowledge across generations. It's only relatively recently (within living memory) that it has ceased to be the case that the majority of the population has some regular contact with organised religion.

In a truly democratic society, a minority would only have rights if the majority had granted those rights in the first place, so if we presuppose the removal of those rights would be undesirable, the only risk would be if the political intelligence of the masses had been lost and there was backsliding into attitudes that (for whatever reason) had been found faulty in the past and which led to the granting of the minority rights.

An alternative, of course, might be that the majority have realised that granting certain rights was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Democracy just means "rule of the people", which allows for a variety of interpretations.

Usually it's something something "government of the people, by the people, for the people". Where the population is the sovereign of the state and any sort of government is either "the people" directly or needs to have a mandate by the people, which is the only legitimate source of power. On top of that you have ideas of individual freedom and equality of the participants as otherwise it's not really "the people ruling" but just a particular person or group wielding inequality and privileges to assert power.

And with respect to the "tyranny of the majority", I always saw that as a red herring and mostly a disingenuous attempt of **tyrants** to uphold their privileges.

Seriously if a majority is out to get a minority that's no longer a theoretical problem of your political system, that's a collapse of the state and society and the potential start of a civil war and/or genocide. If a majority of wolves want to eat a minority of sheep, they're not going to need to vote on that... What they'd vote on would be who gets less than one sheep...

Like what is the alternative? Strike down the majority without a majority mandate? How is that any less tyrannical and what's the legitimization for that? This would no longer be about theoretical ideas about how politics should be organized, but about picking sides, the actual issues that are fought about, as well as military might and practical organization.

That being said your question touches upon a different facet of that namely: "Who is 'the people' to begin with" and "How do you become 'the people'".

Which prompts questions about explicit and implicit groups and their dynamics and who is drawing the boundaries.

And in theory that is pretty simple. A group of people gets together and mutually asserts that from now on they officially form an explicit group. Optionally these constituents of the group might also write down their hopes and aspirations for the groups character as well as their rights and duties within the group.
And being democratic really just means that the legitimacy of a decision comes from within that group. Whether that means that they decide my majority, consensus, by vote or by discussion. That's up to them.

Now if conflict arises within that group, any member could theoretically assert their veto and with that process the entire group would be dissolved (theoretically) or in case of rule breaking they could accept being wrong and face the consequences as being a member and upholding the group is still more valuable to them than the consequences they face. They would then be able to re-group and form anew under different conditions or with different people but theoretically their group would only persist as long as it is mutual. Same for the admission of new members. They again would need to re-group and re-negotiate all the basic rules.

Now in practice for any group larger than a bunch of friends, the individual is usually simply disregarded. If someone doesn't fit, they are either coerced to fit (police and military/"law and order") or "allowed to leave" the group/country (being exiled). Also unlike with a group of friends it's perfectly possible to end up being a member of a group (country) without your active participation. So if you are born or otherwise end up in a country you have no choice, but to enter the group that is holding that place occupied. Either as a member or as a prospect or at a lesser status and they are making the rules not you. The constitution gets rarely renegotiated even if the constituents change regularly. So the unwritten paradigm is that the individual change doesn't matter with respect to the majority that remained the same and so they routinely aren't even asked for their opinion.

So is that particularly democratic? Likely not, but even the flawed and imperfect democracies are still in the minority when it comes to systems of government so the label gets applied to even those who at least try some of those ideas. Also it again exemplified how disingenuous the concept of a "tyranny of the majority" actually is if that last paragraph was not included in their concern, which it never is.

Edit: Rereading that makes it sound more bleak than it was intended to be. The point is not to say that democracy disregards the individual entirely (and is bad because of that). Quite the opposite, the formation of a group as equals (which usually comes with universal individual rights for citizens or even humans in general), the conception of equality of citizens and even principle of majority. Mean that an individual citizen has on average more power and freedom than in many many other forms of government. Sure you're likely won't have commanding authority over others, but only in combination with a plurality/majority/consensus with the rest of the group, BUT a) that's way more power than 99.99% of people would have in a tyranny and b) that also means that other people are not supposed to have tyrannical rule over you (so it's not just a limitation of your power it also limits the power of other people to coerce you).

So tl;dr
'can that happen in what is commonly called "democracy"?' Sure.

'What could Mr.X do about it?' Well apart from not joining, convincing the rest that this isn't good or organizing after becoming a member, not much I guess.

'Is a prerequisite for joining compatible with a democracy?' Depends. When it comes to an explicit group, the probably yes. Though the negotiation of the terms of service could be significantly more free than "sign or leave".
Another case would be if 2 groups occupy one land and one claims it and wants the other to join on their terms. Though in that case that wouldn't be democratic to begin with, would it?